# Maven 2 <resources> inheritance (parent -> child project)

Tags: maven-2, maven, pom.xml

(also posted on maven-users)

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on inheritance of the  elements in pom.xml as relates to resource processing and the WAR plugin.

The documentation for the pom [1] has resources listed under "Elements in the POM that are merged". Some experimentation on my local poms against maven 2.2.1 don't appear to exhibit that behavior. What I see is it looks like  is inherited by child projects (in a multi-module build), but that if any of those projects have their own  block it replaces the parent, not merged. Is that correct?

Example:

```
parent-pom.xml
|
|-> child-pom.xml
```

The following works as I'd expect, with files in dev not included in a final WAR.

parent-pom.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${dev-config.path}</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

child-pom.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${dev-config.path}</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/rules</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/test/rules</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

The following change to the child (removing any declaration for src/main/resources) appears to result in src/main/resource not being considered during process-resources, not inheriting from the parent as I'd expected.

child-pom.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/rules</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/test/rules</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

[1] http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html s

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed, that's what the documentations says. But I confirm that Maven inheritance overrides resources instead of adding to them. This is actually captured in [MNG-2751](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2751), and indirectly in [MNG-2027](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2027), that you might want to bump.

TBH, I'm very curious to see what the maven folks will say on this (I'm personally happy with the current behavior, I don't really want child poms to be "polluted" by specific needs, like exclusions, in a hierarchy) and changing this behavior might break a lot of projects.

Comment: I'm ok with replacement, though it does make some things like management with profiles less elegant. We worked around by using variables that get passed into <exclusion elements>, but it's a little unclean

Comment: @jayshao Note that I'm just expressing a personal opinion, I'm not claiming to detain the truth :) I'll look at the feedback on the maven-users list, I'm curious now.

Comment: @pascal-thivent yeah, didn't see a response fly back, but what we have is workable for now, though easier for child POMs to break than I'd like

Answer (score 6):

As noted in [adding additional resources to a maven pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101462/adding-additional-resources-to-a-maven-pom), this can be worked around using the [build-helper](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) plugin.