# Inherit log4j2.xml from parent project

Tags: maven, logging, architecture, log4j2

I have multiple micro-services, each having it's own log4j2.xml or log4j2.properties. Each of them have a common parent maven project.

So, my question is, can I inherit the log4j2.xml from the parent project in maven? Or is there an approach which is available.

The only thing I can think of is:

- Have a location for the log4j2.xml
- When building my docker image, give the common path to log4j2.xml.

But this seems too cumbersome, I was thinking if it can be achieved better

Answer (score 0):

I had to consolidate my `log4j2-test.xml` files in a multimodule Maven project recently. I used the Maven `testResources` tag as follows (this goes in each child project):

```
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <!-- Copy global log4j2-test.xml file locally -->
            <directory>../src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j2-test.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
        <!-- Copy all other files in local src/test/resources folder so tests can access them -->
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

I believe you should be able to do something similar using the `resources` tag:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <!-- Copy global log4j2.xml file locally -->
            <directory>../src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <!-- Copy all other files in local src/main/resources folder so child project can access them -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I also found this question helpful: [Maven 2 <resources> inheritance (parent -> child project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008065/maven-2-resources-inheritance-parent-child-project)