# Does specifying a resource directory add or replace the default one?

Tags: maven, maven-3

If specifying a custom resource directory:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/spring/</directory>
  </resource>
```

Does it add it to the default `src/main/resources` directory ?

Or does it replace it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding additional resources to a maven pom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101462/adding-additional-resources-to-a-maven-pom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il will replace it, but you can have multiple resource directory.
<s>Do not forget to also add `<filtering>true</filtering>` if you want the same behavior as default.</s>

**EDIT :**
Default behavior is to NOT filter.